# Datasources only found on 1 site in IIS 7

Tags: iis, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

The title is not quite correct, but here is the problem situation:

1. Setup multiple sites on the same IIS 7 server
2. Installed CF10 and it works fine on all sites
3. CFIDE Datasources can only be found for 1 site, not all of them, even though they still work on all sites

To see CF datasources (using RDS), the URL is `sitename/CFIDE/administrator/datasources/index.cfm`. Each site in IIS 7 has the CFIDE directory mapped to it as far as I know. It appears in the site folder structure for all my sites as a virtual directory. I used the Web Server Configuration Tool to remove and re-add ColdFusion to all my sites.

The problem is that applications using RDS can only find datasources for one of my sites. It uses the URL given above `sitename/CFIDE/administrator/datasources/index.cfm` to find the datasources of the site. RDS is not picking up the datasources for any of the other sites.

I tried manually going to `sitename2/CFIDE/administrator/datasources/index.cfm` (sitename2 being the name of a different site in IIS to the one that's working) and I just get this error:

```
"The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."
```

Can anyone suggest how to fix this so the URL will resolve for each site? Otherwise my RDS feature has broken which is not good. If I test the sites themselves, they all work fine and can access my datasources just fine. So something is up with the RDS feature

Comment: I am confused as to what you are doing?  RDS is for development only.  It should be disabled in production servers.  Also, datasources are CF instance specific and not specific to a site in IIS.

Comment: Yes this is a development setup using IIS 7 as the web server

Comment: I'm still not sure why the RDS is not working on multiple sites. It only works on 1 site in Dreamweaver.

Comment: ColdFusion 10 added the ability to administer RDS from the admin UI interface ([reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7ff4.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7ff5)). Navigate to each of your site's ColdFusion administrator page and verify RDS is enabled. Verify other settings while you are there (username, password, etc).

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood something... I have installed the developer edition of CF10 on my local machine which has IIS 7 on it. I have created 3 sites in IIS7 and they all have ColdFusion configured to work. This is my testing server. My production server is remote. If I go to the CF Administrator page on my local machine, I can see all my datasources and RDS is ticked. So why doesn't the RDS work for each of the sites on the testing server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sorted it. Looks like it was a password thing. I had to remove the require password authentication and re-apply it again.